# How do you copy data from a dataframe to another

Tags: pandas, csv, reference, copy

I am having a difficult time getting the correct data from a reference csv file to the one I am working on.

I have a csv file that has over 6 million rows and 19 columns. I looks something like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAY6a.png)

For each row there is a brand and a model of a car amongst other information.
I want to add to this file the fuel consumption per 100km traveled and the type of fuel that is used.

I have another csv file that has the fuel consumption of every model of car that looks something like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzKRP.png)

What I want to ultimately do is add the matching values of G,H, I and J columns from the second file to the first one.

Because of the size of the file I was wondering if there is another way to do it other than with a "for" or a "while" loop?

**EDIT** :

For example...
The first df would look something like this

| ID | Brand | Model | Other_columns | Fuel_consu_1 | Fuel_consu_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Toyota | Rav4 | a | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | Honda | Civic | b | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | GMC | Sierra | c | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | Toyota | Rav4 | d | NaN | NaN |

The second df would be something like this

| ID | Brand | Model | Fuel_consu_1 | Fuel_consu_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Toyota | Corrola | 100 | 120 |
| 2 | Toyota | Rav4 | 80 | 84 |
| 3 | GMC | Sierra | 91 | 105 |
| 4 | Honda | Civic | 112 | 125 |

The output should be :

| ID | Brand | Model | Other_columns | Fuel_consu_1 | Fuel_consu_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Toyota | Rav4 | a | 80 | 84 |
| 2 | Honda | Civic | b | 112 | 125 |
| 3 | GMC | Sierra | c | 91 | 105 |
| 4 | Toyota | Rav4 | d | 80 | 84 |

The first df may have many times the same brand and model for different ID's. The order is completely random.

Comment: well you won't need a while loop, a simple merge would do. If you can run it locally depends on the size of your machine & available memory. I would look into using something like `dask` or `pyspark` but tbf 6 million x 19 should be doable even on a lower spec machine just might take a while.

Comment: also see [mcve]

Comment: If you could give some programable data I'm developers would be happy to help you with your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing updates I was able to put something together that should be able to help you

```
#You drop these two columns because you won't need them once you join them to df1 (which is your 2nd table provided)
df.drop(['Fuel_consu_1', 'Fuel_consu_2'], axis = 1 , inplace = True)
#This will join your first and second column to each other on the Brand and Model columns 
df_merge = pd.merge(df, df1, on=['Brand', 'Model'])
```